# How to apply filter for percentage when it contains strings along with it in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this query to filter out the results below 38 percentage. But when I execute I get the random result with no errors and not the expected results.

```
select Name, Percentage
from datamining.dbo.Register
where percentage <= '30%-40%'
   or percentage <= 'total 40% obtained'
```

The actual table:

```
Name      Percentage
----      ----------
Andrew    30%-40%
Angel     35%
Bob       total 60%
Clare     total 38% obtained
```

The expected result:

```
Name      Percentage
----      ----------
Andrew    30%-40%
Angel     35%
Clare     total 38% obtained
```

There are strings present along with percentage and the query which I wrote doesn't give me the expected results.

Assist me on how to recreate the condition which I have passed so I can achieve the expected result.

Comment: You are doing string comparison. And with the condition `total 40% obtained'. All string begins with numeric is considered less than the string `total ....`

Comment: You should use `numeric` data type for  the `percentage` column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the percentage is less than 100, below code computes the numeric value within the
string column and gives you the list of percentages which are less than or equal to 38. This will not work in all cases as the percentage column is not normalized.

```
SELECT Name, Percentage
FROM datamining.dbo.Register
WHERE SUBSTRING(Percentage, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Percentage),2) <= 38
```

Answer (score 0):

The table should in correct format, here percentage field is in string.

you can compare strings with the filtering conditions, but cannot be compared with '' Mathematical comparisons

Answer (score 0):

You *could* split the string and make the comparison:

```
select r.*
from datamining.dbo.Register r
where exists (select 1
              from string_split(r.percentage, ' ') s
              where try_cast(replace(s.value, '%', '') as int) < 38
             );
```

However, I would say that you have a fundamental problem with your data model.  It sounds like you are trying to store a range of values.  You should probably use `percentage_low` and `percentage_high` or something like that.  A string is the *wrong* way to store these values -- unless, of course this is coming from some third party and you are stuck with this format.